# how can I translate special character in csv

Tags: php, csv, magento, internationalization, translation

this is raw message in Js

```
$.mage.__("Please enter a valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &.")
```

expected message:
Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \ , &.

csv files:

I try to translate this text in csv file like example bellow but it's not work! are there any way to fix it ??

```
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \\ , &.", "abc abc valid Street Address not including " , / , \\ , &."
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &.","abc abc valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &."
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including &quot; , / , \\ , &.","abc abc valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &."
```

Comment: Do you want to generate with these symbols ? how are you sending these data to js ?

Comment: csv map the raw text in Js then translate, 
ex: "word","word after translate"

Comment: then use these statement in a variable .. <script type="text/javascript">var demotext= "Please enter a valid Street Address not including \  /  \\  &."  ;</script>

Comment: \" equal "
its my raw js code :

$.mage.__("Please enter a valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &.")

expect mess: Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \ , &.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: all 3 ways in my csv file above not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add special characters with javascript code :-

```
 $.mage.__("Please enter a valid Street Address not including \' , \\ , \" , \& ")
```

Check this.

In case you need some more special characters then use these code / short codes into your string.

There are some reserved single character escape sequences for use in strings:

```
\b: backspace (U+0008 BACKSPACE)
\f: form feed (U+000C FORM FEED)
\n: line feed (U+000A LINE FEED)
\r: carriage return (U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN)
\t: horizontal tab (U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION)
\v: vertical tab (U+000B LINE TABULATION)
\0: null character (U+0000 NULL) (only if the next character is not a decimal digit; else its an octal escape sequence)
\': single quote (U+0027 APOSTROPHE)
\": double quote (U+0022 QUOTATION MARK)
\\: backslash (U+005C REVERSE SOLIDUS)
\&: ampersand
\r: carriage return
\t: tab
\b: backspace
```

Comment: $.mage.__("Please enter a valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &.")
I already use it, I mean how can I map the message and translate ?? because the csv which I map not working

Answer (score 0):

In csv you have to care about 2 characters: the separator char and the quote char (most common `,` and `"`).

If fields contain a separator they have to be enclosed in double quotes, and if fields contain a double quote this has to be escaped with another double quote (or a `\` Linux style).

So your example file:

```
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \\ , &.", "abc abc valid Street Address not including " , / , \\ , &."
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &.","abc abc valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &."
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including &quot; , / , \\ , &.","abc abc valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &."
```

becomes:

```
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including "" , / , \\ , &.","abc abc valid Street Address not including "" , / , \\ , &."
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including \"" , / , \\ , &.","abc abc valid Street Address not including \"" , / , \\ , &."
"Please enter a valid Street Address not including &quot; , / , \\ , &.","abc abc valid Street Address not including \"" , / , \\ , &."
```

Also don't put spaces between the separator and the field, as in the first line. This could cause some problems with certain parsers.

Comment: My raw js mes :
$.mage.__("Please enter a valid Street Address not including \" , / , \\ , &.")****
Expected message: Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \ , &.****
Csv(not work): "Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \\ , &.", "abc abc valid Street Address not including " , / , \\ , &."

Comment: The csv data is invalid. You have to escape the double quotes inside the fields. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \ , &.","Please enter a valid Street Address not including " , / , \ , &."

add translation in your csv file, after run the below commands:

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f {'your store language code if you use..'}

php bin/magento c:f